Generate two files instead of one
I want to generate a report with quarto. There is two qmd file that are working well. however, on Rstudio, when I launch my _quarto.yml file with quarto render, it generate 2 separate files, instead of a single one. I am looking for the solution.
yaml :
project:
  title: "mytitle"

book:  
  author: "me"
  date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
  chapters:
    - 01_resume.qmd
    - 02_analyse.qmd

format:
  html:
    toc: true                    
    toc-location: left          
    number-sections: true        
    toc-title: "Sommaire"        
    toc-depth: 4                 
    toc-float: true              
    self-contained: true
    css: styles.css             

execute:
  echo: true
  sequential: true


That's how the book in html works. Maybe consider switching to other type of document like manuscript: https://quarto.org/docs/manuscripts/ or chose one-file ouput format like ePub or pdf. Or instead of quarto book use rmd knitr wirh bookdown, see: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3267 and https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6473
